# Concerning motion of conduction electrons under external force

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals, electronic-band-theory

In crystals, because of the periodic potential of the nuclei the allowed energy eigenvalues of an electron in the potential form energy bands, which are separated by energy gaps. Energy eigenvalues and eigenfunctions are functions of the wavevector $k$. Now, in solid-state physics textbooks it is proved that under an external force $F$, for a conduction electron we have
$$\hbar\frac{dk}{dt}=F,$$
which obviously means the wavefunction and the energy of the electron change with time. But considering the fact that under a constant external force the energy eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of the system are different from what they were before, what does $k$ refer to now?

Comment: $k$ still refers to the crystal momentum. Since the system still has the same translational symmetry (since it is a crystal), $k$ is still well defined.

Comment: @JonCuster, what do you mean by 'crystal momentum'?

Comment: Periodicity in real space of the crystal implies periodicity in momentum. Bloch states and all that...

Comment: @JonCuster, Usually we bring $k$ into the first Brillouin zone. What I'd like to know is which eigenfunctions the $k$ refers to: the old ones or the new ones?

Comment: $E(k)$ may change, but $k$ remains the same, enforced by the atomic positions in the lattice.

Comment: @JonCuster, according to $\hbar\frac{dk}{dt}=F$, $k$ changes with time.

Answer (score 0):

An electron in the conduction band is a (nearly) free electron. Therefore using de Broglie relation you can write
$$\vec{p}=\hbar\vec{k}.$$
Then the formula you have given is nothing but Newton's law
$$\vec{F}=\frac{\mathrm{d}\vec{p} }{\mathrm{d} t}=\hbar\frac{\mathrm{d}\vec{k} }{\mathrm{d} t},$$
and the $\vec{k}$ refers to the de Broglie wave for the free electron.

Comment: In this case $k$ doesn't refer to the wavevector of free electrons. The electrons are not free; they feel the periodic potential.

Comment: but if one can write $\vec{F}=\frac{\mathrm{d}\vec{p} }{\mathrm{d} t}$ then is not this mean that there is no potential, otherwise one would have something like $\vec{F}=\frac{\mathrm{d}\vec{p} }{\mathrm{d} t}-\vec{\nabla}U$; $U$ being the crystal potential?